# Should the data transformation to the uniform [0,1] always be performed in copula modeling, even for Archimedean copula families?

Tags: data-transformation, copula

Is the data transformation to the uniform [0,1] always required in copula modeling, even for Archimedean copula? I have read some sources stating that the first step in copula modeling involves transforming the data to the uniform [0,1], but doesn't Archimedean copula have a special property to handle data that is not within [0,1]?

Comment: if you have sources, it is typically a good idea to cite them

Comment: Yes, the first step in the copula model is to transform the data into standard uniform margins, for all copula models. Copula then joins these margins to provide you with the dependency structure.